# Filtering a dataframe returns an "Empty Dataframe"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a dataframe by column values but I keep getting the return value as an empty dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd


def get_count_RS(filepath,column1,word):
  df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
  sec = df[column1].str.count(word).sum()
  print(sec)

  first = df[df['RS_Tier'] == 'Mid']
  print(first)
```

The first part works. I am able to get the integer count value as the output (878.0).

But, when I try to use the filter first, the return is an empty dataframe with nothing.

[image]

Comment: It simply means that no row matched your condition. Are you sure `df['RS_Tier']` contains `Mid`?

Comment: Hi @Chris, it 100% contains that value, which is why I am so confused.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataframe before and after each part, and your expected output?

Comment: Hi @ATL, I added a sample. Please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Try `df['RS_Tier'].unique()` and confirm `Mid` indeed exists.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data types of the columns using df.dtypes. If RS_Tier is an object, you can convert to string first to be able to filter that way.